# iPhone UIwebview with embedded quicktime video?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When I load a HTML page with a .MOV embedded video on my App using a UIWebview it appears a broken icon, any idea? The same HTML page on Iphone Safari works fine and the media player is started without problem...

Answer (score 1):

Where is the webpage? Is it embedded in your app? If you not giving the UIWebView a URL to load it from the server where it is make sure you set the baseURL properly so that the webview knows how to handle handle relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

When using the app sandbox, apple stops WebKit from accessing it's com.apple.security.WebKit.PluginAgent.

You must enable these in the entitlements file with the appropriate entitlement of

Add this line to the entitlements file as an ARRAY:
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name

in this array add the value : com.apple.security.WebKit.PluginAgent

and you should get your app to give sandbox permission so the app can access the quicktime movie plugins.

Hope this helps, if this doesn't solve the problem maybe the movies are missing... ;)